# how to retrieve a signed value stored in unsigned variable

Tags: c, integer, embedded, type-conversion

I have a signed 8-bit value (in two's complement) stored in an unsigned uint8_t variable. 
That happens because the value is read from an external peripheral via spi interface something like:

uint8_t return_value = read_spi(uint8_t register_address)

The datasheet of the peripheral says that that specific address contain a two's complement value, so the bit pattern inside return_value should be a signed 8-bit value.

I know the obvious way to retrieve the signed value: strip off the sign bit, if negative flip bits, add 1, multiply by -1.

I wonder if maybe there was a more elegant way.

Comment: If the value you have in the register is a signed value you have to simply handle it as signed value, no conversions have to be made, a simple cast is enough. The generic routines for reading peripheral registers are written in a way to allow whichever value to be read in. This is something like a buffer reading where the buffer is defined as generic char, then assigned to a structure or something. What you have to do is simply: `int8_t MyVar = (int8_t)read_spi(RegAddr);`

Comment: int8_t MyVar = (int8_t)read_spi(RegAddr);
I agree that this might work, as also user694733 says, but isn't this a type casting, from any point of view?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be type casting? The cast operator is right there: `(int8_t)`. And why does it matter? This conversion is well-defined, safe and portable.

Comment: You do not need an arithmetic operation to retrieve the signed value - it is merely a reinterpretation of the *same* bit pattern - assign it to a signed type (with or without an explicit cast) and carry on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on two's complement system, you can just do:

```
int8_t result = return_value;  // or assign the from function directly
```

Strictly speaking the behaviour is *implementation defined* (N1570, 6.3.1.3) when value is negative:

> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. ...
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

In practice, it just works; `intN_t` types are guaranteed to be two's complement and without padding bits. Typical modern machines don't bother to perform any extra operation on unsigned to signed assignment, and just copy the bits. Check your compiler manual, if you want to be sure.

Comment: There can't be padding bits on character types (explicitly forbidden by the C standard), nor can there be padding bits on the stdint types - they are guaranteed to be two's complement.

Answer (score 4):

In C you are allowed to type-pun through a `union`.

```
union foo
{
    uint8_t ui;
    int8_t i;
} f;
```

Set `f.ui = return_value` then read back the signed value using `f.i`.

Comment: You mean "pun" not "prune"

Comment: Oops. I'll get my 2 year old to read to me this evening. Let's relearn English!

Comment: I like the term *type-pruning* - I am going to find a use for it! ;-)

Comment: It even made sense to me, I thought it would prune the sign bit :)